# When posing a rigged mesh I get really weird results

Tags: mesh, rigging, pose-mode

So I am new to blender and I followed this tutorial to rig my arms model:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0xkPLAhFrY&list=PLKklF7YNi0lOM0C8r_L3JN3oTC6AY9iFE

After I parent my mesh with automatic weights and start rotating the lower arm, the hand mesh gets dislocated. Obviously, that's not what I want my arms to do, so my question is: how do I stop the hands from extruding?

I think, that it's somehow related to the way I modeled the arms or/and the way the rigging is done.

By the way, here's the tutorial I followed to draw the arms:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm23eX8S3sQ&list=PLKklF7YNi0lOM0C8r_L3JN3oTC6AY9iFE

Here is my file:
https://we.tl/t-SwMYNsKu5x

The tutorial guy uses an older blender version, maybe that's the problem.

Thanks in advance

[image: Before rotating]
[image: After I rotate the lowerArm]

Comment: could you please send out the blend file too?

Comment: Sure, I'll put it in the question body and here https://we.tl/t-SwMYNsKu5x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into weight paint mode on the object and select your "hand.L" vertex group. You'll see that the vertex group for hand.L is partially assigned on the geometry of the lower left arm. Remove that area from your vertex group. In the image below, that red on the lower arm before the wrist shouldn't be there for the hand.L group.
[image]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/introduction.html

[image]

See how I have the upperArm.l group selected and lowerArm.l part of the mesh is light blue, that means weight for the upper arm is still assigned to the mesh for the lower arm.

[image]

Select the verts for lower arm and hand, with the upperArm.l group select, assign a weight of 0 to those verts for the upperArm.l group. That fixes the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It still doesn't work, here is a link to a video to show what I did:
https://youtu.be/WMDTd5MfT1Y
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The weight still isn't set properly for the group "upperArm.l". Go into edit mode/vertex select on the arm object. Select your hand and lower arm verts and assign a weight of 0 to those with the vertex group "upperArm.l" selected.

Comment: Edited the answer with screenshots.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I'm glad I managed to fix it. It's very kind of you to help newbies like me. Thank you so much!